# c# Take user input, search excel for that input and copy row to new spreadsheet if found

Tags: c#, excel

I have searched far and wide for a solution to this, but it is simply over my head. My end goal is to automate our catalogue creation.

What i want to do is this:

I have a master product spreadsheet with 9000+ rows, each row is a new product, containing SKU, title etc. (SKU is a product code, e.g EG6541SBLU, for those who didn't know)

The user would paste a list of SKUs into say a textbox, and for each SKU it would search the master sheet (col A) and copy the entire row to a new spreadsheet.

The end result is a spreadsheet with all product info of the user inputted list.

This spreadsheet will then be imported through indesign into a catalogue.

This essentially allows us to dump a list of SKUs into my program, and it return a spreadsheet ready to import into indesign.

I appreciate this is a large project, but any help whatsoever getting this complete would be a huge help.

Thanks,

D

EDIT: Here is how far I got. This is from Microsoft and I literally don't know where to turn next, hence why i asked here.

```
//Start Excel and get Application object.
                oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;

                //Get a new workbook.
                oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
                oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

                //Add table headers going cell by cell.
                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "part_no";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "sku";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "description";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "price";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "color";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "'@image";

                //Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "F1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "F1").VerticalAlignment =
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
```

Comment: This is not a code providing site so if you have tried something share your code where you are stuck. Else, break it down to simpler tasks like read an excel file, search, insert data in an excel file and then try and combine it all :). You can surf for such examples and there are a lot of libraries that could be helpful

Comment: Hi, i've tried a lot of code but didn't have anything solid that was worth posting; so i didn't bother. I can write to a spreadsheet, open one etc. It's the find and copying results i'm struggling with.

Comment: If what you want to do is really just within Excel then you might be able to just do it in VBA. (Although I hate VBA.) Write a macro that responds to a cell being updated by populating VLOOKUPs in adjacent cells or a custom function that looks up data in another sheet. That way entering a part number in one column will cause data to appear in adjacent columns in the same row.

Comment: How are you opening the excel? What are you using Interop? OpenXML? Some third-party library? Share the code you are using to opening the excel and you might get better responses on how you can extend it

Comment: @ScottHannen I thought of something in excel, but i'd prefer it to just be a simple windows form that my colleagues can fill in and it auto creates if that makes sense.

Comment: In that case I'd break up the problem, writing as much code as possible without either the form or Excel. Create a class that represents the data you want to retrieve. Write some classes that take a SKU or list of SKUs and retrieve data. It doesn't matter where the list comes from or where the data comes from. Then it gets easier to fill in the other pieces because they're smaller. One end is entering the list into a form. The other end is looking up the part numbers in an Excel workbook. That end could be EPPlus. You open a spreadsheet and load a dataset, then query that dataset.

Comment: @FortyTwo Sorry, I have updated my question to include some code. I am using interop

Comment: I recommend running from interop as if it's going to chase you and hurt you. It won't - it will just make you very sad. EPPlus (OpenXML) lets you open and read an Excel workbook as data from your application. Interop is actually creating and running an instance of Excel - it's similar to executing VBA from your .NET app.

Comment: Interop has `Range.Find` method with which you can search cells.

Comment: @ScottHannen Where can i get started with EPPlus? It sounds interesting

Comment: @FortyTwo I know, I just have no idea how to translate that into this solution lol

Comment: Check out this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus.DataExtractor/. Follow the Project Site link. I've used this. It lets you define a class for your data and then easily populate a collection of items from a range in a worksheet. What's great about this is that you can read from the worksheet and have your data in memory. That's the end of your interaction with reading the worksheet. Once you've got that data you can do anything with it - display it on screen save it to another workbook, etc.